# Erlang term_to_binary hex output

Tags: erlang-shell

Anyone knows how to make `term_to_binary` in erlang console print the output in hex format instead of its standard list of unsigned decimal bytes?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option in io:format but you can build something like:

```
A =[s,f,g,t,w,{t,g}].
Bin = term_to_binary(A).
io:format("<<~s>>~n", [[io_lib:format("~2.16.0B",[X]) || <<X:8>> <= Bin]]).
```